# powershell substring of substring

Tags: powershell, substring

I'm trying to substring a substring of a text file in order to cut out the text I need from a text file.

In this example if the file contains the following

> this is a test example
>   second line of text
>   third line of text

I want to remove everything before second, then get everything between "second" and "third line". So the output would be

> second line of text
>   third line

This is what I have and it works if put a hardcoded length in $second, but I can't get the length correct as a variable:

```
$text = ( Get-Content -raw Test.txt | Out-String ).Trim() 

$first = $text.IndexOf('second')

$second = $text.Substring($text.IndexOf('second'), ($text.length-1))

$third = $second.Substring(0, $second.IndexOf('third line'))

$text.Substring($first, $third) | Set-Content file2.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

couple of ways you could do this:

first- specify what you dont want

```
Get-Content -Path textfile | 
  Where-Object {$_ -NotLike 'this is a*'} | 
    Set-Content file2.txt
```

second- specify what you do want

```
Get-Content -Path textfile | 
  Where-Object {$_ -Like 'second*' -or $_ -like 'third*'}  | 
    Set-Content file2.txt
```

or

```
Get-Content -Path textfile | 
  Where-Object {$_ -match '^(second|third)'}   | 
    Set-Content file2.txt
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank  you!

Answer (score 0):

Here I was getting text data and then splitting it by single line (**`n**) doing so will make an array of string lines. Then I get strings number by array enumeration [1..2].

```
PS C:\> $string = @"
this is a test example
second line of text
third line of text
"@

$string.Split("`n")[1..2]
second line of text
third line of text
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but my real file is a lot larger than the example so not sure how to translate it